# Has anyone here tried to encode and decode Scytale Cipher on Python?

Tags: python, encryption

I can't seem to find any helpful tutorials/ guides online and I'm stuck in a rut. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should try to think about how a scytale transposes the letters of the text written on a strip wrapped around it. To do that it might help to draw a table. For example, you could have a skytale on which you can write 5 letters around the circumference and you might want to write "How does this work" on it. You could do that in the following way, writing 3 letters on each row (removing spaces and capitalizing everything).

|  | col0 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **row0** | H | O | W |
| **row1** | D | O | E |
| **row2** | S | T | H |
| **row3** | I | S | W |
| **row4** | O | R | K |

If you read this table column by column, you get the letters in the order they would appear on the strip after unwinding it from the skytale. It all boils down to a relatively simple pattern. If you think of the grid as a matrix, to encode/decode you essentially just have to transpose that matrix (the rows become the columns and the columns become the rows). There are several ways you could try to implement the encryption and the decryption, and you should try to find a way to do it yourself first. Here is one way to do it. If you use 0-based indexing for the characters in your plaintext, dividing the index of a character by the number of rows gives you the row of that character in the table, whereas the remainder of the division (i.e. modulo operation) gives you its column. The following code computes the ciphertext index of each plaintext letter using this observation.

```
def encrypt(rows, plaintext):
    assert len(plaintext) % rows == 0
    n = len(plaintext)
    columns = n // rows
    ciphertext = ['-'] * n
    for i in range(n):
        row = i // columns
        col = i % columns
        ciphertext[col * rows + row] = plaintext[i]
    return "".join(ciphertext)

def decrypt(rows, ciphertext):
    assert len(ciphertext) % rows == 0
    return encrypt(len(ciphertext) // rows, ciphertext)
```

These functions only work when the length of your plain-/ciphertext is divisible by the number of rows. One approach to make the scheme work in all cases could be to extend the text with random characters when its length is not divisible by rows. Notice that you can essentially just use the encryption function to decrypt as well (as you can see in the code). Just to be sure, I hope that you are aware of the fact that this encryption scheme is extremely easy to break. You should never use it in practice!